# My usb flash drive is not showing up in nautilus in Ubuntu 15.10. How to fix?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I have a Kingston 32 Gigabyte USB flash drive that is detected in the Disks program but not showing up in the Files program.

Comment: When you plug your flash drive in try running `fdisk -l` and see if it is listed.

Comment: What is the file system of your USB flash drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/659351/ubuntu-doesnt-automatically-mount-usb-flash-drive?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

In the Disks program, what is the partitioning scheme for your flash drive?

Usually it is a single partition if FAT32 type. If it is any different, please comment. Note down the device name for the partition (Example: `/dev/sdb1')

Follow these procedures in a terminal:

- `cd /media/<yourusername>'`
- `sudo mkdir flashdrive`
- `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 flashdrive`
- `cd flashdrive && ls-ltr`

The contents of your drive should be listed by now. Most likely, Nautilus will also show your usb drive. To manually unmount the drive, follow these step in a terminal:

- `cd /media/<yourusername>`
- `sudo umount /dev/sdb1`
- `sudo rm flashdrive -r`

The problem appears to be that the system isn't automatically mounting the dive. If you have any problem following this solution, leave a comment. You can also create a script to do all this job automatically.

Comment: The partition is (/dev/sda)

Comment: You seem to be doing something incorrect here. The notation /dev/sdX where X is a letter refers to a physical device: Harddisk, Pendrive. The notation /dev/sdXY where Y is a number refers to a partition on that physical device.  Yours is most likely /dev/sdb1 for the pendrive.

Answer (score 1):

Is the USB specifically not getting detected in Ubuntu 15.10 ? Have you tried plugging it in to other systems ? And did you remove it mid-way while formatting ?

If its a pen-drive problem and supposing you are not concerned about the data on the stick then you can use gParted.

Installation Guide : http://ubuntuguide.net/install-graphical-partition-editor-gpartedin-ubuntu-linux

After installing , launch gparted from the terminal. On the top right corner select your pen-drive /dev/sdb1 and create a partition table. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing in the thumb drive in all the way.  I know it sounds silly, but in my case that's what I was doing wrong. The sleeve thing was making it seem like I had it in all the way even though it wasn't.